"java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message) " I am constantly getting this error in react-native
/*
I was trying to takeover the project of previous developer who has left before I joined in my new company. And its constanly popping the same error no matter what I do to resolve it
*/
Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

Try:



Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 27s
582 actionable tasks: 577 executed, 5 up-to-date
PS C:\projects\BEXMobileAppV2-albin\android>
I tried to change react-native version , changed the java version ,tried install compatible libraries
